# Selenium code opens the Chrome Browser and goes to the URL but does not type the UserID and Password and so on

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber

I'm new to Selenium Webdriver with integration to Cucumber and I cannot do the Login successfully.

**Here's my Feature file:**

```
Feature: Validate user can login successfully

@tag
    Scenario: Successful login
        Given User is on the Login screen
        When User enters UserID and Password
        And User clicks Login button
        Then Home Page is successfully displayed
```

**Here is my Step Definition:**

```
public class Steps

{
    WebDriver driver;

    @Given("^User is on the Login screen$")
    public void User_is_on_the_Login_screen() throws Throwable
    {
        System.out.println("Pumasok dito");
        //OPEN THE BROWSER
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\I689629\\eclipse-workspace\\uat-core\\src\\test\\resources\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://go/eruat8");
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @When("^User enters \"(.*)\" and \"(.*)\"$")
    public void User_enters_UserID_and_Password() throws Throwable
    {
            //ENTER THE FID
            driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserDefault")).sendKeys("User123");
            //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            //ENTER THE PASSWORD
            driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassDefault")).sendKeys("Password123");

    }

    @And("^User clicks Login button$")
    public void User_clicks_Login_button() throws Throwable
    {
        //CLICK THE LOGIN BUTTON
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"frmDefault\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/input")).click();
        //}

    }

    @Then("^Home Page is successfully displayed$")
    public void Home_Page_is_successfully_displayed() throws Throwable
    {
        System.out.println("Home page is displayed");
    }
}
```

**And here's my test runner:**

```
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)

    @CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report", "json:target/cucumber.json" },
    features = {"src/test/resources/features" }, glue = { "StepDefinition" })

    public class TestRunner

    {

    }
```

Can someone help me please. Thank you.

Comment: Please declare `private WebDriver driver;` outside the method as a class variable. Then you should be able to access the driver in the other steps in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Steps

{

 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\I689629\\eclipse-workspace\\uat-core\\src\\test\\resources\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe"); 

 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

@Given("^User is on the Login screen$")
public void User_is_on_the_Login_screen() throws Throwable
{
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://go/eruat8");

}

@When("^User enters \"(.*)\" and \"(.*)\"$")
public void User_enters_UserID_and_Password() throws Throwable
{
        //ENTER THE FID
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserDefault")).sendKeys("User123");


        //ENTER THE PASSWORD
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassDefault")).sendKeys("Password123");

}

@And("^User clicks Login button$")
public void User_clicks_Login_button() throws Throwable
{
    //CLICK THE LOGIN BUTTON
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"frmDefault\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/input")).click();

}

@Then("^Home Page is successfully displayed$")
public void Home_Page_is_successfully_displayed() throws Throwable
{
    System.out.println("Home page is displayed");
}
}
```